# Are eigenfunctions of differential operator always orthogonal

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have the Laplace eigenproblem:

$\Delta f+\lambda f=0$

with boundary conditions (say, Dirichlet)

and I have found two distinct functions $f_1, f_2$ and scalars $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ such that

$\Delta f_1+\lambda_1 f_1=0$

$\Delta f_2+\lambda_2 f_2=0$

Is it certain that $f_1, f_2$ are orthogonal? if so how to prove it?

Comment: Use Green's first identity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_first_identity
Apply for $u = f_1, v = f_2$ and $u = f_2, v = f_1$

Comment: Orthognal in which Hilbert space? $L^2$? $H^1$? $H^1_0$? (It holds for everyone of them, but the proof might slightly vary)

Comment: @F.Conrad I meant $L^2$ space